# How to convert RSA private key to Openssh Private key

Tags: ssh, openssl, rsa, openssh

I have a key beginning with "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY". I want to use that key for ssh from linux machine. I think I need to convert to "BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY". But I don't know it can be possible. And I can't google it. Please help me with this.

Comment: RSA private key should work well with OpenSSH without any conversion. What does make you think that the conversion is needed?